# Number of ways in which you can climb a staircase with 1, 2 or 3 steps - memoization

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have to calculate the number of ways one can climb a staircase taking 1, 2, or 3 steps at a time. I know of ways to do this, for example, `f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)` but I would like to know why in my implementation (which is different from the above) I do not get the correct answer. I'm using a `for` loop instead.
The problem is every time a value is returned that is non-zero but that value includes a pre-calculated answer, and hence is not used by my code. What changes do I need to make?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
int nWays = 0;

int stepPerms(int n, map<int, int> &memo) {

    if (memo.find(n) != memo.end())
        return memo[n];
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 0)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        int retVal = stepPerms(n - i, memo);
        if (retVal == 0)
            memo[n] = ++nWays;
    }
    return memo[n];
}

int main() {
    map<int, int> memo;
    cout << stepPerms(5, memo);//cout << stepPerms(3) << endl;
}
```

Comment: In the loop starting `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)`, what does `stepPerms(n - i, memo);` return when `n` is 1 and `i` is 2? The value that stepPerms` returns for that case causes an incorrect result. Where is the code for that case. Why does it return −1? What should it return instead?

Comment: Recursion and global state is a nasty combination.

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “I do not get the correct answer.” Always state the observed program behavior and the desired behavior instead. (And, if the program takes input, state sample input that reproduces the problem.) For example, state “This program generates output ‘4’, but the correct output would be ‘7’.” For this question, you should show several possible arguments to `stepPerms` and their corresponding desired results, both so that people can check their understanding of your description of the problem and so they can test the code.

Comment: The sentence “The problem is every time a value is returned that is non-zero but that value includes a pre-calculated answer, and hence is not used by my code.” is unclear.

Comment: Also, what should `stepPerms` return when `n` is zero? How many sequences are there in which the sum of the elements in the sequence is zero? Hint: If a sequence is empty, what is the sum of the elements in it?

Comment: `nWays` increments when it's possible to climb `n-i` steps, but you need to add the number of possibilities. And your base case is wrong.

Comment: @molbdnilo Recursion and global state/static variables are my last resort because this is a problem I'm trying to solve on HackerRank, and I'm not supposed to change the original function definition (takes an `int` and returns an `int`). However I have changed it to take a `map` as well because I just want to know why code did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
map<int, int> memo;

int stepPerms(int n) {
    if (memo.find(n) != memo.end())
        return memo[n];
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    if (n == 2)
        return 2;
    if (n == 3)
        return 4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        memo[n] += stepPerms(n - i);
    return memo[n];
}

int main() {
    cout << stepPerms(27);
}
```

Comment: For the base cases, you actually only need `if (n <= 0) return n == 0;` (0 for negative `n`, 1 for zero).